# C# base class have a derived class member and it loops

Tags: c#, oop, loops, derived-class

I have this class:

```
public class GameData
{
    public int[,] mat { get; set; }
    public int dim { get; set; }
    public int goal { get; set; }
    public Game game { get; set; }

    public GameData()
    {
        game = new Game();
    }
}
```

And this two other derived classes:

```
public class Game :GameData
{
    private Mover m;

    public Game()
    {
        dim = 4;
        goal = 16;
        mat = new int[dim, dim];
        m = new Mover();
    }
    /*Methods*/
}

public class Mover : GameData
{
    /*Methods*/
}
```

It loops because `Game` constructor calls `GameData` constructor and so on.
How can I do?
I am starting whit OOP programming and I am not sure this three classes are the best way to set the program. `GameData` contains common datas, `Game` contains the method to play and `Mover` contains a group of method used by `Game`

Comment: From your description, there may be no reason for them to inherit from each other at all.

Comment: I don't think Game should inherits from GameData at'll. It is not a correct OOP approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly inheritance doesn't make any sense here. Inheritance is an "is a type of" relationship (in other words, is `Game` a type of `GameData`? I doubt it.

Instead use composition! Just have class hold the objects they care about. Composition is a "has a" relationship, which makes a lot more sense in your case. Honestly, I would invert the `Game`/`GameData` relationship, a `Game` probaly holds `GameData`; not the other way around. Only you know what you need though.

```
public class GameData
{
    public int[,] mat { get; set; }
    public int dim { get; set; }
    public int goal { get; set; }
    public Game game { get; set; }

    public GameData()
    {
        game = new Game();
        dim = 4;
        goal = 16;
        mat = new int[dim, dim];
    }
}

public class Game
{
    private Mover m;

    public Game()
    {
        m = new Mover();
    }
    /*Methods*/
}

public class Mover
{
    /*Methods*/
}
```

Comment: Maybe the Game constructor should not have dim, goal and mat, them should probably be initialized in GameData class.

Comment: @yosoy excellent point, my code was not compilable because of that copy-paste. If game knows about them, it should pass them to GameData's constructor (which would reinforce flipping that relationship). Fixed my code anyways.

Comment: @Vitto So game and mover should hold a "GameData". If they need to have the same object, then `Game` which holds both, would pass the `GameData` object to the `Mover` class. Does that make sense? This, btw, is what I meant by flipping your composition relationship.

Comment: @Vitto Great! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence

> public GameData()
>       {
>           game = new Game();
>       }

makes no sense; as GameData is the parent, is not logical to have a child inside the parent. Obviously that makes a loop, as you are creating a Game : GameData over and over with that sentence.

Think about inheritance you want, as you are using it incorrectly with Mover too.

Answer (score 0):

Well you definitely have a circular reference which is a design smell.  You *could* stop the infinite loop by checking for `null`:

```
public GameData()
{
    if(game == null)
        game = new Game();
}
```

Or pass the `Game` instance in to the constructor rather than creating a new one - hard to say what's *correct* without knowing more of your overall design.